# Customizing widgets in ArcGIS Viewer for Flex 3.4 to support French?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-viewer, widget, internationalization, flash-builder

How can I customize my widgets in flex viewer such that the labels will be in French?

I work with flash builder 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much you searched for solution, in case if you not checked Adobe docs please check the link on localization  [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_localization_pt1.html).